# Invalid Json Response when accessing third-party service with Wix Corvid

Tags: json, fetch, response-headers, velo

I am attempting to gather details about real estate properties through an external API. I've gone over their documentation relentlessly but can not figure out why I am receiving the following error:

`invalid json response body at https://api.gateway.attomdata.com/propertyapi/v1.0.0/property/expandedprofile?address1=34%20Karen%20Court&address2=Bridgeport20%CT reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position`

For reference, I am posting my code. If anyone can provide any input or guidance I would greatly appreciate it!

Backend Code:

```
import { fetch } from 'wix-fetch';
import { wixData } from 'wix-data';

export function getDetails(address, citystatezip) {
 const url = 'https://api.gateway.attomdata.com/propertyapi/v1.0.0/property/expandedprofile?address1=' + address + "&address2=" + citystatezip;
 let headers = {
        "apikey": "xxxxxxxx",
        "accept": "application/json"
    };
 let options = {
        headers: headers
    }

    console.log("Url: " + url);

 return fetch(url, { method: 'get' })
        .then(response => {
 return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
 return data;
        });
}
```

Page Code:

```
wixWindow.getCurrentGeolocation()
    .then((obj) => {
        let timestamp = obj.timestamp; // 1495027186984
        let latitude = obj.coords.latitude; // 32.0971036
        let longitude = obj.coords.longitude; // 34.774391099999995
        let altitude = obj.coords.altitude; // null
        let accuracy = obj.coords.accuracy; // 29
        let altAccuracy = obj.coords.altitudeAccuracy; // null
        let heading = obj.coords.heading; // null
        let speed = obj.coords.speed;
        console.log(obj)

        reverse(latitude, longitude)
            .then(geocode => {
                console.log(geocode)
        let id = geocode.results[0].place_id; 

        details(id)
            .then(detailed => {
                console.log(detailed)       

                $w("#input12").value = geocode.results[0].address_components[0].long_name + " " + geocode.results[0].address_components[1].long_name;
                $w("#input10").value = geocode.results[0].address_components[3].long_name;
                $w("#input11").value = geocode.results[0].address_components[5].long_name;
                $w("#text37").text = geocode.results[0].formatted_address;

                $w("#googleMaps2").location = {
                    "latitude": latitude,
                    "longitude": longitude,
                    "description": geocode.results[0].formatted_address

                };

                let address = geocode.results[0].address_components[0].long_name + " " + geocode.results[0].address_components[1].long_name;
                let city = geocode.results[0].address_components[3].long_name;
                let state = geocode.results[0].address_components[5].short_name;
                let citystate = city +"%2C" + "%20" + state;
                console.log(citystate)

                const uri = address;
                const encoded = encodeURI(uri);
                console.log(encoded);

                getDetails(encoded, citystate)
                    .then(got => {
                        console.log(got)
                    })

            });
    });
```

Thank you in advance for any input or guidance you can offer. I have spent hours trying to figure this out to no avail.

Stay safe and stay well

Comment: Add a `console.log(response);` before you `return response.json();` to see what it comes back with. Even better: put a breakpoint on `return response.json();` and inspect the value directly.

Comment: @JohnH hank you so much for your response. I made a few edits to the code, please see above.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but the console logging needs to happen inside of your `getDetails()` function. Logging afterwards is already too late, because it's trying to return JSON. As I mentioned in my first comment, you need to inspect the value of `response` to see if `response.json()` is failing.

Comment: I added the breakpoint as suggested and now the result shows up as undefined. Any thoughts or guidance? @JohnH